# ssh2 module fails silently with creds that succeed from CLI

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, ssh, google-cloud-platform

I've successfully `ssh`'d into Google Cloud Compute via CLI with a command like the following:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-ssh-key me@ipnumber
```

But using the [`ssh2`](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2) module isn't giving any output, including errors.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;

var connSettings = {
  host: IP, // 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XX'
  port: PORT, // XXXX
  username: ME, 
  privateKey: privateKey, //fs.readFileSync(location, 'utf8')
  passphrase: passphrase,
  password: password
};

var conn = new Client();

conn.on('ready', function() { //first example in README
  console.log('Client :: ready');
  conn.exec('uptime', function(err, stream) {
    if (err) throw err; //nothing
    stream.on('close', function(code, signal) {
      console.log('Stream :: close :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal); //nothing
      conn.end();
    }).on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('STDOUT: ' + data); //nothing
    }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('STDERR: ' + data); //nothing
    });
  });
})
.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error('err', error); //nothing
})
.connect(connSettings);
```

I'm tailing `/var/log/secure` as I'm debugging the node script and I can see log entries when I `ssh` in and close the session from CLI, but nothing at all when I try through node `ssh2`.

What could be causing this connection to fail silently?

Comment: Wrong port and it's waiting for the handshake to timeout? Try adding `debug: console.log` to your connection config to see what's happening/not happening under the hood.

Comment: @mscdex I can see when I log that object they all are correct. Seems like there should be at least some error.

Comment: Can you post the debug output somewhere? Also what version of `ssh2` are you using?

Comment: @mscdex there isn't one that i can see. where could i find one?

Comment: When you add `debug: console.log` to your `connSettings` object, it should print debug output to your terminal/console. Copy that to a gist or something and link to it here.

Comment: @mscdex Aha. That actually shows I'm connected: `DEBUG: Client: Trying XXX.XXX.XXX.XX on port 8080 ...
DEBUG: Client: Connected`. Yet, the `Client :: ready` does not print and I don't see the `uptime` output or an entry in /var/log/secure.

Comment: @mscdex Thanks for taking a look at this. Any ideas on what this issue could be?

Comment: It's hard to say without being able to review the requested (full) debug output. Also, are you *sure* port 8080 is the correct port? You don't show that port being used in your OpenSSH client example.

Comment: @mscdex [Here](https://gist.github.com/thomashibbard/78d921694270bb068ffe67d14017591c) is a gist with the full debug output.

Comment: @mscdex I'm sure the port is 8080. I'm not sure what you mean by this: _You don't show that port being used in your OpenSSH client example_ . I have the port in my connection settings.

Comment: If ssh2 is using a subprocess you could try running `strace -F python script.py 2>&1 | less` and searching for an exec call and then try running this by hand with the appropriate debug flags.

Comment: If the strace approach doesn't work and you have access to the server you could run a second ssh server on the machine with a lot of debugging: `/usr/sbin/sshd -D -p $NEW_PORT -d -d -d` (The output from this contains sensitive information)

Comment: If 8080 truly is the correct *ssh* port, you might run tcpdump/wireshark to see if the server is sending *anything* after the connection is made. Also, it would be interesting to see the most verbose debug output from the OpenSSH client when connecting. If you could post the results of either or both of these, that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**: I have it on good authority that your client would *log the server ident string*, and that is sent immediately upon connection. So if you *don't* see that information, it must be the case that the server is not sending *anything*.
Now since you tried with CLI SSH and it works, once we exclude the impossible, the only remaining explanation, unlikely as it may seem, is that **you are not connecting to the same server/port**. For some reason, port 8080 on the destination server isn't running a SSH2 server.

*One* possible interpretation is this: the server is running something else on port 8080, that allows connection but doesn't send anything initially (e.g. a HTTP server). When you connect with the CLI SSH, you *think* that it is using port 8080, but for some reason that directive in the ssh_config file does not kick in, and the CLI SSH connects to the true SSH server, and works, while the node SSH connects to a different server, and that's why it does not work.

To check, try telnet'ting to port 8080 of that server and verify that it does respond with a SSH2 banner:

```
Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
^C
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

**If it does not answer** with the "SSH-..." banner, I think this demonstrates sufficiently that the CLI SSH is connecting elsewhere. Where? To discover this, run again the CLI SSH with debug:

```
ssh -vvv xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ... 2>&1 | grep "Connecting to"
```

(You'll have to exit by hitting Ctrl-C). This should give you:

```
debug1: Connecting to whatever [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port XYZK
```

And that xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and XYZK values are the ones you'll need to pass to the `node` client.

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**

I am not familiar with `nodejs`'s SSH2, but I had a SSH2 library (closed source, at that) play this exact trick to me some months ago. "Connected..." followed by *nothing*.

It turned out that the client was using a cipher that the server did not support, and for some reason while this is shown by OpenSSH2's CLI client, the library chose not to display the error. It was quite messy to get to the bottom of things.

I see from the GitHub page that some ciphers require "node v0.11.12 or newer". Is this your case? If not, you may want to try updating `node`.

In any case I'd follow @AttRigh's suggestion and run a sshd on the server in debug mode. If you cannot:

- log the ssh2 CLI client's output in full debug mode and extract what cipher it uses,
- set up a sshd server with that cipher and no others,
- run your node client against that server.

Also, now that I come to think of it, you might set up a sshd server anyway with default settings, and ensure that you can connect to *that*. This would circumscribe somewhat the problem.

Comment: The issue isn't ciphers because there would be debug output when the handshaking begins, much like with the OpenSSH client when it shows what each side is offering in each category (host key format, DH, cipher, hmac, compression). In fact, the ssh2 client doesn't even see an ident string from the server, because it would actually log that right after connecting.

Comment: @mscdex , I've experimented, and come to the conclusion that your suspicion on port 8080 not presenting a SSH2 server is very likely correct. Updated answer accordingly (I'll probably end up *deleting* it altogether - the question likely falls in the "simple errors" category and thus a candidate for closing).

Comment: @LSerni Telneting (`telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 8080`) gives me this output: `Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
Connected to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.bc.googleusercontent.com.
Escape character is '^]'`. I think I understand what you're saying, but I'm not really sure how to fix it. Can you explain? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it looks like this is the issue. I got port 22 and when I connect using that, I see the attempt in the logs. I got auth failed, but that is a separate issue I believe :) Thanks so much!